# Is it possible to automatically trigger(send) data from Amazon SQS to the SQL database using an API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

As for now I have created a button and when that button is clicked the data goes from Amazon SQS to the SQL database, but I want is that the Amazon SQS automatically triggers or sends the data, each time a new record is inserted in the SQS and then further send it to SQL DB.

As far as I have explored, I have found that we can use AWS Lambda to trigger data automatically. But i am not totally sure.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no direct way of doing this. Lambda doesn't support SQS trigger now but they are planning to add it soon.
Till then if you want to use lambda anyways then you can send data from SQS to SNS and put a trigger on SNS from lambda for further processing to store it in DB.

Comment: Thanks, the answer was really helpful. I did not knew that Lambda doesn't support SQS trigger. So I want to know that instead of SQS, can i use Dynamo DB or S3 and then use Lambda to trigger or send the data to SQL DB. Is it possible ? Please do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. Btw what is your use case? Because s3 and dynamodb are way different in terms of their use. As per your problem statement S3 would be better option for you. So, are you planning to go from sqs to s3 to lambda to db? Seems you are taking long route

Comment: Actually I am very new to using Amazon AWS. So pardon me if i am wrong. But I was thinking of going from "S3 to lambda to SQL db" or "DynamoDB to lambda to SQL db", and eliminate the use of SQS. Am I correct ? For now the use case is that i am filling the details like First Name, Last name etc. in a form and then on click of Submit button, the data goes directly into Amazon SQS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dyamodb is nosql db so in your case I don't find any use of it as you are already saving the data in RDBMS.
S3 is object based storage system, you will have to store your form data in the form of a object in s3 bucket.
For example, you can choose to save the form data in terms of json object on s3 bucket and configure an event 
with lambda to let lambda know each time you insert new object in your bukcet so as to process it further to store into DB.
Please note that by default your s3 bucket is public so store data carefully.

Comment: Really a nice explanation. Thanks for your quick response, you save a hell lot of time of mine. I am trying to get used to AWS, and the explanation you have provided will be really helpful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The way that SQS works is that you need to poll it to pull data down. It is not an event-driven system. You can build a lambda that polls the queue if you want it to be more real-time.

If you want an event driven system, you'll need to use something like kinesis. In that example, data will be put on a kinesis stream and then trigger a lambda function that writes the data to SQL.

Comment: Note that AWS has publicly mentioned that they're working on making SQS → Lambda a real thing you can do, but no timeline yet as far as I know: https://twitter.com/sqlbot/status/992232833115713536